# Can I create my own server plug-ins with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I know that you can download plug-ins for your server, but I want to make all the stuff with command blocks. I have just started researching command blocks, but I have researched alot, and I know a quite alot. Please tell me, is it possible, or would I have to get plug_ins?

Comment: In what way do you want command blocks to act like plug-ins? What are you wanting to accomplish with command blocks/plug-ins? Is *what*  "possible"? Command blocks can work on servers, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Try looking at and developing for [GM4](http://www.gm4.co/gamemode4/#about), which seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are many features that command blocks are lacking, the most obvious Events support and variables in general (apart from the scoreboard).

While you cannot make everything you can with a plugin, you can make many things. It depends on what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I kinda disagree with this answer.  The things that can't be accomplished with command blocks that can be done with plug-ins is limited and are mostly edge cases.

Comment: @MBraedley Commandblocks cannot register commands, and are chunk dependant. Their behaviur will be erratic if they are not near enough of the player.

Comment: But datapacks also use commands and they are location independent. Check out the Asphodel Meadows datapack for an example of the epitome of commands stuff.